# SQL add condition to where clause if variable has data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I set variables at the top of my SQL script for date and then call those variables in many other places to keep things simple.

I'd like to add a conditional where clause to add an AND statement but ONLY if there's data in the @test_patient field.

```
declare @from_date date
set @from_date = '2017-01-01 00:00:01'

declare @to_date date
set @to_date = '2017-12-31 00:00:01'  

declare @test_patients NVARCHAR(MAX)
set @test_patients = ('123','234') 

select * from table
where 
    date between @from_date and @to_date
    AND other things
    AND other things...
```

...And here's the part I need help with  ...

```
    IF @test_patients IS NOT NULL 
        Add this->  and p.PatientId in @test_patients               
    ELSE nothing... move along...
```

Basically, the code would grab all patients, unless I specifically put in some test patients that I want it to find. If I Don't populate any test patients in my variable, I don't want it to look for specific patients.

Comment: I'll suggest `Dynamic SQL`

Comment: I'm also not sure that NVARCHAR(MAX) is the right way to make an array. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OR`:

```
select * from table
where 
    date between @from_date and @to_date
    AND other things
    AND other things...
    AND (@test_patients IS NULL OR p.PatientID = @test_patients)
```

Comment: This works for one patient at a time. I learned that if I want an array of patients, I have to use a table variable instead of a varchar... which makes sense... but it really complicated my where clause. I tried a bunch of ways and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Frantumn If you have a list of patients (123, 124, 125, 126, ...), then you can change the '=' with 'IN'.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by this way

```
select * from table
where 
    date between @from_date and @to_date
    AND other things
    AND other things... 
    AND (@test_patients IS NULL OR (@test_patients IS NOT NULL AND p.PatientId in @test_patients    ))
    AND (@test_patients IS NULL OR (@test_patients IS NOT NULL AND otherthing....    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
WHERE p.PatientId in @test_patients OR @test_patients IS NULL
```